# How do I export a custom kernel image on raspberry Pi compute module 4 / io board in headless mode and verify if it has loaded successfully

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, yocto, raspberry-pi4, mmc

How do I export a custom kernel image on raspberry Pi compute module 4 / io board in headless mode and verify if it has loaded successfully. I have not been able to understand if it is getting loaded properly or not.

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff, it doesn't work, you share the code, and *then* we comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend hooking up a UART -> USB device to uart0 on the IO board. Once you hook that up, you can open up a program like `screen` to open up a serial connection to the device. Be sure to add `ENABLE_UART = "1"` to your `local.conf`.